# mongoose: updateMany with $and does not work properly

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
db.dbDB.collection("buy").updateMany(
  {
    $and: [
      { profit: { $eq: null } },
      { tp_buy: { $gte: incomingData.bid } },
    ],
  },
  {
    $set: {
      profit: true,
      execute_p: incomingData.bid,
    },
  }
);
```

I have this `updateMany()` function.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("asdfeasd"),
    "profit" : true,
    "tp_buy" : 1.16583,
    "execute_p" : 1.16487
}
```

However, as it shows my db is updated even though the `incomingData.bid` has not exceed the `tp_buy`.

Before, modifying `profit`, it is valued as `null`.

Console.logging `incomingData.bid` returns `number` and `tp_buy` is stated as `double` on MongoDB.

How can I only update when the document has a `profit` value `null` and `incomingData.bid` is greater than `tp_buy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query

- i think you have the comparison wrong, try this if you can
- instead of `1.2` put the `incomingData.bid`
- `incomingData.bid > tp_buy` is like `tp_buy< incomingData.bid`

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tdN6qyQTKe_)

```js
db.collection.update({
  $and: [
    {
      profit: {
        $eq: null
      }
    },
    {
      tp_buy: {
        $lt: 1.2
      }
    },
    
  ],
  
},
{
  $set: {
    profit: true,
    execute_p: 1.2,
    
  },
  
})
```